# i need dialog should be white transpaerent in android Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

anybody can help me for getting the white and transparent Background

with the help of

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
    android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

it transparent the dialog i need white faded sort of thing that background screen in dialog will be slightly visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setAlpha` method of `ColorDrawable` to make a `semi-transparent` backgroud [read more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#setAlpha(int))

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(Color.parseColor("#50000000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks ishrat problem resolved....! in the below image there are two button having small image of right or wrong and these are on actvity and infront there is dialog having high alpha for blurring i want this right and wrong should not be blur.  [image shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Oht.png)